# How to remove first and last curly braces in a Json in wso2 esb

Tags: json, esb, wso2-esb

> Json

```
{
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "status": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "status": ""
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "name": "",
        "status": ""
    }
}
```

In this code, I would like to remove first and last curly brace, I didn't found any substring or trim function in wso2 esb.
Can anyone please help.

Comment: JSON you are using is invalid ... try to format it in a correct way

Answer (score 0):

Should be possible using XSLT, Xpath or Script mediator. Here are some links that might help.

[Mediating+JSON+Messages](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI600/Mediating+JSON+Messages)

[Script+Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Script+Mediator)

[Xpath functions](http://www.edankert.com/xpathfunctions.html)

Comment: Martin Hald,Thank You, I have done that in a complete different way based on my output required. I will also look into the links.